# importing from maven sibling modules

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

The project structure is as follows:

```
/proj-root
   /proj-lib
   /proj-cli
```

`proj-root` defines the `proj-lib` and `proj-cli` projects as its (maven) modules. It has `pom` packaging while the other two have `jar` packaging. I added a dependency on `proj-lib` in `proj-cli/pom.xml`

Using the IntelliJ IDE I can import my project without any issues. Building and running works fine both inside the IDE as well as when running the `mvn` command from a terminal.

However, I am missing `import` statements in `proj-cli`.

Imagine a class `Util` in `proj-lib/src/main/java/Util.java`. Without ever importing it (explicitly) I can use this class inside `proj-cli/src/main/java/Main.java`. Trying to manually import the class with `import groupId.artifactId.Util;` fails because this path cannot be resolved.

While many imports can be tedious, I actually like seeing all the stuff coming from elsewhere, including sibling modules. So my question is - is this implicit import intended? How could I explicitly import it? And while I didn't got to this point yet, what if I have to fully qualify artifact and group ID of such an import to avoid naming conflicts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to differentiate between the Maven parts and the Java parts.

`groupId` and `artifactId` are Maven specific parts.

The `import` is Java and your `Util` class has no [package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package?useskin=vector).
A class package represents the directory tree a source file is placed in. For Maven by convention places the main source in `src/main/java`. That is your source root. And that is where your `Util.java` is placed. It is not in a subdirectory therefore it has no package.

If you had your `Util` class for example in `src/main/java/my/proj/lib/Util.java` it would be in the Java package `my.proj.lib` and you could import it with `import my.proj.lib.Util;`

Regards naming conflicts: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that but it is common (but not required by any mean) to start package names with the reversed domain name of the project. E.g. if the project homepage would be https://my-awsome-project.com all packages could start with `com.my-awsome-project.*`.

Same conventions exist for Maven where the `groupId` is usually the reversed domain name of the owning project. Since domain names are kinda unique this prevents most naming conflicts.